# Is it possible to limit parameters passed to a method to constants?

Tags: java

I have a class that has some constants, I have a method and I do like to restrict it's parameters to those constants defined in the class, is there a way to make this happen in java?

Comment: Explain youself. You mean limit varags?

Answer (score 6):

Use enums for this. They **are** constants that allow for compile-time type checking, and in fact this is one of the very reasons that they were created.

Answer (score 2):

Constants:

```
enum DistanceUnit {
  MILE,
  KILOMETER
}

double calculateCaloriesBurned (double distanceWalked, DistanceUnit unit);
```

Along the same lines, suppose you didn't like people walking negative distances:

```
class Distance {
  private double value;

  public Distance (value) {
    if (value < 0) { throw new IllegalArgumentException(); }
    ...
  }
}

double calculateCaloriesBurned (Distance distanceWalked, DistanceUnit unit);
```